# AngularJS Dynamic TemplateUrl Value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to pass an already dynamic value to my directive to fetch a templateUrl for this value. Let me explain with some Sourecode:

```
<p ng:repeat="cell in field.Cells">
   <cell-element handler="{{cell.handler}}"/>
   <!-- cell.handler is e.g. "User" -->
</p>

myapp.directive('cellElement', function() {
  return {

    restrict: 'E',       

    templateUrl: function (tElement, tAttrs, $compile) {
      return '/ajax/' + tAttrs.handler == undefined ? 'foo' : tAttrs.handler +'.html';
    },       
 }
 });
```

Unfortunately, the value of tAttrs.handler is always the literal expression "{{cell.handler}}" instead of the respective value. I tried so many different ways - any guess?

UPDATE:

```
myapp.directive('cellElement', function() {
return {        
   restrict: 'E',
   scope: { handler: '=handler' },
   template: '<ng-include src="\'/ajax/\' + handler"></ng-include>'    
}
});
```

As workaround i used another approach that works. But i would prefer the initial way by using the templateUrl function as i e.g. want to check if "handler" is a valid value.

Comment: Try `handler="cell.handler"` without curly brackets.

Comment: Already tried, does not work. Still the same literal value.

Answer (score 2):

I think that this alternative can work:

```
myapp.directive('cellElement', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',       
    template: '<div data-ng-include="templateUrl"></div>',
    link: function ($scope, iElement, attr) {
        $scope.templateUrl= $scope[attr.handler];
    }

 }
```

And you have to cosume without backets:

```
<p ng:repeat="cell in field.Cells">
   <cell-element handler="cell.handler"/>
   <!-- cell.handler is e.g. "User" -->
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that probably the template is not compiled, so the value you want is not yet interpolated. If you tried to retrieve it in the link function, it would work.